# Julia nested loop

Tags: julia

I am trying to find the duplicate value which occours the first in a list or array. I created the below code which worked in Python and trying to replicate it in Julia, but not getting the desired result. Can you please help?

```
def firstDuplicateValue(array):
    # Write your code here.
    index = float('inf')
    for x, i in enumerate(array):
        for j, k in enumerate(array):
            if i == k and x != j and j > x:
                if j < index:
                    index = j
    if index == float('inf'):
        return -1
    else:
        return array[index]
```

I have created the same code in Julia as below but I am getting the desired result -

```
function firstDuplicateValue(array)
    index = Inf
    for (ind_1, value_1) in enumerate(array)
        for (ind_2, value_2) in enumerate(array)
            if value_1 == value_2 && ind_2 > ind_1  
                if ind_2 < index
                    index = ind_2
                end
            end
        end
    end
    if index == Inf
        return -1
    else return array[index]
    end
end
```

I know there are other optimum ways of doing it, but this is just to learn basics of Julia.

**added from an answer by the OP**: It worked for me, I was providing the wrong input to the function, it was a typo.

Comment: I've voted to close the question (since it was due to a typo), but a couple of Julia tips that may be useful in other code you write: 1. prefer to use `pairs(array)` instead of `enumerate(array)` if you want to get index and value. 2. `Inf` is a `Float64` value, but array indices are generally `Int` values, so there's a type instability in the `index` variable. Try to keep you variables in the same type within a function, for eg. here you could assign `index = length(array) + 1` or `index = typemax(Int)` instead of assigning `Inf` in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, I was providing the wrong input to the function, it was a typo.